# Trouble with form_with hash of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that currently looks like this:

```
<%= form_with method: :get do |f| %>
    <div class='search_param'>
        <h3>Departure Airport:</h3>
        <%= select_tag('search[departure_airport_id]', options_for_select(@airports, params.dig(:search, :departure_airport_id)), :prompt => '-') %> 
    </div>
    <div class='search_param'>
        <h3>Arrival Airport:</h3>
        <%= select_tag('search[arrival_airport_id]', options_for_select(@airports, params.dig(:search, :arrival_airport_id)), :prompt => '-') %> 
    </div>
    <div class='search_param'>
        <h3>Number of Passengers:</h3>
        <%= select_tag('search[passengers]', options_for_select([1, 2, 3, 4], params.dig(:search, :passengers)), :prompt => '-') %>
    </div>
    <div class='search_param'>
        <h3>Date:</h3>
        <%= select_tag('search[flight_date]', options_from_collection_for_select(@flights, 'flight_date', :flight_date_formatted, params.dig(:search, :flight_date)), :prompt => '-') %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

which submits to this controller:

```
class FlightsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @airports = Airport.all.map{|a| [a.airport_city, a.id]}
    @flights = Flight.all
    @search = params[:search] ? search_params.select{|k, v| v != ''} : nil
    if @search
      @results = !@search.empty? ? Flight.where(@search).includes(:departure_airport, :arrival_airport) : @flights
    end
  end

  private

  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:departure_airport_id, :arrival_airport_id, :flight_date)
  end
end
```

However, I want to use a model to automatically populate the fields after the form is submitted so that the user chosen value doesn't disappear. I think it would look something like this:

```
<%= form_with model: @flights, method: :get do |f| %>
        <div class='search_param'>
            <h3>Departure Airport:</h3>
            <%= f.select(:departure_airport_id, options_for_select(@airports), :prompt => '-') %> 
        </div>
        <div class='search_param'>
            <h3>Arrival Airport:</h3>
            <%= f.select(:arrival_airport_id, options_for_select(@airports), :prompt => '-') %> 
        </div>
        <div class='search_param'>
            <h3>Number of Passengers:</h3>
            <%= f.select(:passengers, options_for_select([1, 2, 3, 4]), :prompt => '-') %>
        </div>
        <div class='search_param'>
            <h3>Date:</h3>
            <%= f.select(:flight_date, options_from_collection_for_select(@flights, 'flight_date', :flight_date_formatted), :prompt => '-') %>
        </div>

        <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
    <% end %>
```

with a slightly updated controller:

```
class FlightsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @flight = params[:search] ? Flight.new(search_params) : Flight.new
    @airports = Airport.all.map{|a| [a.airport_city, a.id]}
    @flights = Flight.all
    @search = params[:search] ? search_params.select{|k, v| v != ''} : nil
    if @search
      @results = !@search.empty? ? Flight.where(@search).includes(:departure_airport, :arrival_airport) : @flights
    end
  end

  private

  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:departure_airport_id, :arrival_airport_id, :flight_date)
  end
end
```

However I then am losing the params[:search] hash I was using before, making it difficult to feed these values back to the form / select values. I'm sorry if I'm leaving any information out, I am still fairly new to Ruby / Rails. Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Firstly, in the form, you should use a single model object(`@flight`) instead of an ActiveRecord relation(`@flights`). If you've provided a model object, then it is expected that the form inputs `f.select(:departure_airport_id, options_for_select(...)...` will generate HTML for THAT model object, meaning the resultant HTML input will have the `name` attribute like `flight[departure_airport_id]`. Because the HTML DOM is being generated for a specific model object i.e `@flight` instance. [See Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)

Comment: @Masroor That was it, thank you! I figured it was something simple. If you want to submit an answer I can mark it as correct!

Comment: happy to help :) It's all right, we're good!